# preg_replace for replacing everything of a variable

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace

I actually got a problem, in my situation i select
information from a MYSQL Database saved into $data.

and i have 2 arrays for preg_replace.

this is an example :

```
$repl();
$repl[0] = '/bull/';
$repl[1] = '/found/';
$repl[2] = '/search/';

$replto();
$replto[0] = 'This is not a ballon';
$replto[1] = 'This has been found';
$replto[2] = 'Im looking for it';

$data = array();
$data[0] = '/mynickname/search';
$data[1] = '/somebulls/search';
$data[2] = '/mcdo/found';
$data[3] = '/bump/search';
$data[4] = '/blood/bull';

echo preg_replace($repl,$replto,$data);
```

Ok, but the output of preg_replace is this :

```
/mynickname/Im looking for it
/somebulls/Im looking for it
/mcdo/This has been found
/bump/Im looking for it
/blood/This is not a ballon
```

... but I want this output :

```
Im looking for it
Im looking for it
This has been found
Im looking for it
This is not a ballon
```

I'm new in php, i solved a lot of problem but this is a problem that i haven't found solution.

Can you help me please?

Comment: a mix of `strrpos` (http://php.net/strrpos) and `substr` (http://php.net/substr) should do the trick easily.

Comment: Well, the code is working exactly as you have it...  I think your logic is incorrect here.   If `search` is replaced with `Im looking for it`, why would you think that `/mynickname/search` would automatically remove the mynickname part?  It's only replacing the piece you told it to.

Comment: wow ... easily?... not for me, i was thinking it was just an affair of additionnal put in "preg_replace" ... like in SQL when using the % in LIKE.

Comment: Yes @charlie74 you said right, i hope i can find a method to take the entire line of the array $data because i edit the visual for users, and they don't want to see the path (ex : /mcdo/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the result you want, it looks like you want to do something like:

```
$repl();
$repl[0] = '/.*bull/';
$repl[1] = '/.*found/';
$repl[2] = '/.*search/';
```

Comment: /* would be 0 or more occurrences of /. That's not what you're looking for. Then on top of that, / is being used as the pattern delimiter, so the * really doesn't know what to apply to.

Comment: Great thanks, it work perfectly. Can't Up Vote that answer :/ i have no reputation. Now i can :)

Answer (score 1):

Great thanks it work perfectly.

put like

```
$repl();
$repl[0] = '/.*bull/';
$repl[1] = '/.*found/';
$repl[2] = '/.*search/';
```

Sorry for the late answer, can't come earlier.

Great thanks again.